# Play sound during webrtc / get playback device from other audio element

Tags: javascript, webrtc, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I am trying to figure out how to play a sound on the LOCAL headset during a webrtc call.

This ought to be as easy as:

```js
function playsound() {
new Audio(
    "data:audio/wav;base64,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")
  .play();
  }
  
async function startaudio() {
await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true});
}
```

```html
First <button onclick='startaudio()'>start audio</button><br/>
Then <button onclick='playsound()'>play sound</button><br/>
PS. Demo doesn't work in code snippets due to security not allowed to get microphone
```

However, it seems that during a webrtc call this is being played back on another audio device than the headset.

How do I force it to use same audio device as the ongoing webrtc device is using?

EDIT: As I figured out, the problem is not related to webrtc at all, but rather `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` for headsets that switch to another audio device when microphone is activated.

Bonus question: Why does this very short sound often don't play unless you spam click the button?

Comment: What browser are you using? I can't reproduce in any browser on macOS: https://jsfiddle.net/g8f3dwzn/ For what it's worth, you can try to check if the <audio>'s `sinkId` has been set, but I doubt it.

Comment: @Kaiido Your jsfiddle doesnt actually get permission to open microphone (getUserMedia), so it plays just fine because it hits the main speaker.

Comment: What? You have to grant it the access to the microphone when prompted. Doing so you'll see that it works fine.

Comment: @Kaiido The Iframe used by jsfiddle and code snippet to run the code doesn't give permission to even ask about microphone usage in firefox and chrome atleast. But I did figure out the solution.

Comment: It does, you need to run the fiddle from the URL I provided, not from the bare `https://jsfiddle/`

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out... I got the clue from this source: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/

```js
let dtmfSound = null;
let audioCtx = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

function playsound() {
  const sampleSource = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
  sampleSource.buffer = dtmfSound;
  sampleSource.connect(audioCtx.destination);
  sampleSource.start(0);
}

async function startaudio() {
  await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true
  });
}

async function Init() {
  let dtmfdata = await fetch("data:audio/wav;base64,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");
  dtmfSound = await audioCtx.decodeAudioData(await dtmfdata.arrayBuffer());
}

Init();
```

```html
First <button onclick='startaudio()'>start audio</button><br/>
Then <button onclick='playsound()'>play sound</button><br/>
PS. Demo doesn't work in code snippets due to security not allowed to get microphone
```